# Disable Tor Network

Tags: network-configuration

I want the security implementations of the tor browser but prefer to use multiple hop vpn's (Chaining).

I have downloaded the 32 bit linux package and would like to know what I need to do to configure it.

Comment: @Gunter Are you trying to use the harden version of Firefox aspect of Tor Browser Bundle, but route traffic through a VPN? I don't believe there is native support for such

Answer (score 1):

Tor already provide multiple hop capability, so you don't really need to add it.

If you set a vpn (with multiple hop) on your machine for internet connection, tor browser will use it to connect to the tor network.